# How to autowire object in java spring on runtime as it has multi subclasses?

Tags: java, spring

for example:
I have an interface like

```
class TestAnimal {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("animal")
    private @IAnimal animal;

    void hanlde (){
        animal.some();
    }
}
interface IAnimal {
    void some();
}

@Component
class Lion implements IAnimal{
    void some(){}
}

@Component
class Tiger implements IAnimal{
    void some(){}
}

@Component
class Hippo implements IAnimal{
    void some(){}
}
```

when i run server, i am getting exception like

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.Animal' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: Lion,Tiger,Hippo
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:173).

How to resolve this issue. any way to create runtime object initialization?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen. Which concrete implementation of `IAnimal` would you expect `animal` to be?

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

Comment: private @IAnimal animal; why do you use @ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring doesn't know which bean to inject. There are three beans in your code: lion, tiger and hippo. So above the animal field, you should select which bean you want to inject with @Qualifier annotation. E.g. if it's a lion you've to write @Qualifier("lion"). And also remove @ in the line "private @IAnimal animal;"

If you want dynamically autowire you should look https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamic-autowire.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the implementation name on the Qualifier annotation ("lion", "tiger", "hippo"), not the abstract class/interface.